# Get return value directly from Dialog (Confirm a Choice)

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I want to add a ConfirmationDialog to a Button from a RecyclerView.
I have an Interface Listener (Observer) that calls a function in the MainActivity that receives the confirmation as a boolean.

My Problem is:
I want to use this Confirmation Dialog for multiple purposes.
So it would be easiest, whenever a confirmation is needed to just open the Dialog and wait for the return value.
Something like this:
// val returnValue = dialog.show()

Is there some way to get a dialog to act like this?

Here is my Code:

Relevant from MainActivity

```
// The function that gets called when the InterfaceListener 
        //is called from the ConfirmationDialog
override fun sendInput(bool: Boolean) {
        // not the functionality i want
    }

// this gets called from the button in RecyclerView
override fun onTicketDoneToggleClick(ticket: Ticket) {

        // open ConfirmationDialog and get the return value
        val confirmed = true

        if(confirmed)
            if(ticket.isDone) {
                ticket.setIsDone(false)
                val result = database.saveTicket(ticket)
            }else {
                ticket.setIsDone(true)
                val result = database.saveTicket(ticket)
            }

        // update the RecyclerView
        showRecyclerView()
    }
```

And this is the ConfirmationDialog

```
class ConfirmationDialog(private val context : Context, question : String) : AlertDialog(context){

    private lateinit var binding : ConfirmationDialogBinding

    // interface for InputListener for ParentActivity
    interface OnInputListener {
       fun sendInput(bool: Boolean)
    }
    lateinit var listener : OnInputListener


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ConfirmationDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            listener.sendInput(false)
            dismiss()
        }

        binding.btnConfirm.setOnClickListener {
            listener.sendInput(true)
            dismiss()
        }
        setOnDismissListener {
            listener.sendInput(false)
        }

    }
}
```

I don't really know if this functionality is possible as i heard that the Dialog is asynchronous?

If there is no way to do it like this:
What can I do, to use the sendInput() in a smart way to use it for multiple different types of confirmations and the corresponding actions?

(I wouldn't think it is smart/elegant to set a variable in main to indicate what sendInput should do, right?)

Comment: btw i just noticed with ondissmisslistener return value will always be false but i will fix that xD

Comment: Use higher Order function for that. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Comment: Can you elaborate in what way you would use them?

Answer (score 0):

you can use High-order functions
this code may help you

```
class ConfirmationDialog(private val context : Context, question : String,
var onClick: (( sendInput: Boolean) -> Unit)? = null) : AlertDialog(context){

    private lateinit var binding : ConfirmationDialogBinding

   


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ConfirmationDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            onClick?invoke(false or ture)
            dismiss()
        }

       
    }
}
```

and override `onClick` function in your activity or fragment when create dialog

```
val dialog = ConfirmationDialog(context , "qq",
onClick = onClick{

}
)
```